# Мониторинг подключенных к wifi устройств

Tags: c#, wifi, arp, tp-link

Как ясно из заголовка - мне необходимо получить полный список ip-шников, подключенных к wifi сети. Делаю я для того чтобы можно было в реальном времени мониторить кто подключается или отключается от сети. Пока шарился в инете - нашел вариант через пинг и arp. Оба варианты меня не устраивали т.к. везде были оговорки (на пинг не все отвечают, а arp хранит кеш и просто запоминает всех с кем комп взаимодействовал). Есть вариант сделать через api роутера, возможно ли это? В моем случае роутер tplink, но интересует в целом универсальное решение какое-то. Пишу на c#, если это имеет какое-то значение в данном случае.
P.S. Дубликаты видел, в них описаны варианты которые работают на arp и ping, выше я описал почему они не подходят

Comment: Наверное только читать документацию к роутеру